# WebClient could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webclient, dotnet-httpclient

I've already search on Stack Overflow (and google), but can't find the specific answer that solves my problem.

I want to read some content out of a page. I've tried to use `Webclient`, but that gives me this error:

> The type or namespace name 'WebClient' could not be found (ae you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've tried to search on google how to solve this error, but didn't find a correct answer (I've also tried `HttpClient`, same result).

How do I make sure that I get the content of his specific page?

Btw, this is what I have right now:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
// Use google as test page
string downloadString = client.DownloadString("http://www.gooogle.com");
```

And I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community and ASP.Net v5

Comment: Did you add `using System.Net;` to your `using` directive?

Comment: @S.Akbari Yes, I tried.. Then I get the error: `A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations`

Comment: OK. Probably you have not placed it at the beginning of the file!

Comment: @S.Akbari I did (see comment at the answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure you have reference to `System.dll` in your project.

Also either include `using System.Net;` to usings directive section of the source code where you're planning to use `WebClient` or use its fully-qualified name, i.e.:

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient()
```

Comment: Thanks! `var client = new System.Net.WebClient()` works perfect! But do you also know why `using System.Net;` gives me this error?: `A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations`

Comment: @MZeinstra `using` directives should be at the very beginning of the file. Where do you placed it?

Comment: I've placed this `<script runat="server">using System.Net;</script>` at the very top of my .aspx file

Comment: @MZeinstra hmmm... you've mentioned ASP.NET v5 so `aspx` was last thing that came in my mind. In apsx file you have to use `<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>` instead.

Comment: Ahh okay, sorry. That works just fine :D What am I using then? You think?

Comment: how i can add System.dll