# A magical situation：I can‘t find class WebcCinet in UWP

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I have add `using System.Net; using System.Net.Http;`
When I input `WebClient`, it shows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9m5H.png)

“Could not find the type or namespace name "WebClient" (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)”

It means it dosen't exist this class.
I don't know why.......

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show us that message a) In English. b) In the text of your post rather than as an image.

Comment: what version of .net are you targetting?

Comment: Have a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/35775059/7124761

Comment: Try with : var client = new System.Net.WebClient()

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale, Thank you! I will search the Stack overflow more carefully next time.

Comment: Is that solve your problem?

Comment: @ Prashant Pimpale No, the error is still there.And i use HttpClient now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP projects should not be targettting WebClient. Use the "HttpClient" from the Windows.Web.Http namespace instead.